# Bus or taxi from Coonor (or Ooty) to Coimbatore?

Tags: india, buses, taxis, tamil-nadu

On 23rd Dec, I (and 2 friends) will be starting from **Ooty** (Udagamandalam) and need to reach **Coimbatore** Train station before **15:00** (from where there is a train at 15:25 to Chennai - Booked).

Now there is a "toy train" from Ooty (09:15) to Coonor (10:25) which we want to travel from. But the problem is I can't see any reliable (apart from taxi) way to get from Coonor (which is between Ooty and Coimbatore) to Coimbatore, online.

Please point out if there are local means (bus or taxi) from Coonor to Coimbatore?
If not that then from Ooty to Coimbatore.

Please take notice of the time I need to reach in Coimbatore. BTW the taxis can be booked online, but they are more costly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are definitely buses between Ooty and Coimbatore, but you may have to change in Mettupalayam. They also run through Coonor. Looking at my travelog, it took about three hour from Coimbatore to Mettupalayam which is relatively flat. But the part between Ooty and Mettupalayam is much slower but really nice.

Also the bus station you arrive at in Coimbatore is not in the center, and it will take a while to get from there to the train station.

I think if you take an early bus in Ooty you can make it in time for your train, but taking the toy train may take too much time. If you have enough time, take the toy train the day before and then the bus back to Ooty in the afternoon.

The toy train was very busy when I was there earlier this year, you had to make reservations weeks in advanced.

Just double-check at the bus station in Ooty.

Comment: I returned from trip :) What we did - went on toy train, from Coonoor to Ooty. The buses from Ooty to Coimbatore are very frequent, so it is the best option. And few seats are available to get on from Coonoor, so thats also possible.